# R and Rstudio Docker vs Binder

Tags: r, docker, android-binder

My problem is that I can't use R-studio at my work place as the IT does not support it  . I want to use R and R-studio that installed on my personnel laptop on my company laptop ( using a modern browser which is behind firewall ) . Some of the options   I am thinking of two two things

1. should I need to  build  a docker for R and R-studio (I see base images are already available) , I am mostly interested in basic  R , Dplyr  (haven ,xporter, and Reticulate ) packages .
2. Should I have to use a binder .  I am not technical person and my programming skills are very limited can any one suggest me way .

What exactly are the difference between using Docker option vs Binder ?
I know I can use R-Studio online and get my work done but with the new paid account I am running out of project hours and very slow sometimes . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples beyond [the modern RStudio MyBinder example](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda):

- https://github.com/fomightez/pythonista_skewedf
- https://github.com/fomightez/r_phylogenetics_worshop
- https://github.com/fomightez/chapter7/tree/master/binder

[The modern RStudio MyBinder example](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda) has been set as a template on GitHub so you can use

The first one is for a special use of a package not on conda. And I started that one from square one.
The other two were converted from content by others to aid in making them Binder-ready.

You essentially list everything you need from conda in the `environment.yml` along with the appropriate channels.  If you need special stuff not on conda, you need [the other configuration files](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/config_files.html) included there.

Getting everything working can take some iterations on adding things, letting the image get built, and testing your libraries are available. Although you seem to think your situation is not overly complex.

The binder launch badges you see are just images where you modify the URL to point the MyBinder federation site at your repository. Look at the URL and you should see the pattern where you put studio at the end of the URL pointing at your repo. The form at [MyBinder.org](https://mybinder.org/) site can help with this; however, most often it is easier to just adapt a working launch badge's code copied from elsewhere. The form isn't set up at this time for making the URLs for launching to RStudio.

Download anything useful your create in a running session. The sessions timeout after 10 minutes, although RStudio usually keeps them active.
Lack of Persistence and limited memory, storage, & power can be drawbacks.   The inherent reproducibility and portability are advantages.

MyBinder.org doesn't work with private repos. If you have code you don't want to share, you can upload it to the temporary session, using the repo for specifying the environment. You could host a private binderhub that does allow the use of private git repositories; however, that is probably overkill for your use case and exceed your ability level at this time.

GitHub isn't the only place to host repositories that can be pointed at the MyBinder system. If you go to the [MyBinder.org page](https://mybinder.org/) and click where it says 'GitHub' on the left side of the top line of the form, you can see a list of the sources at which you can host a repository and point the system to build an image and launch a container with that specified image.

Building the image from a source repository takes some minutes the first time. Once the image is built though on the service, launch is typically less than 30 seconds. Each time you make a change on the source repo, a build is necessary. Some changes don't cause the new build to be as long as the initial one as some optimizing is done to only build what is necessary after a change. Keep in mind there are several members of the federation around the workd and if traffic on the internet gets sent to where the built image isn't yet available, it will be built from scratch again first.

[The Holepunch project](https://github.com/karthik/holepunch) is out there to offer some help for users working in the R ecosystem; however, with the R-Conda system that is now integrated into MyBinder it is pretty much as easy to do it the way I described. Last I knew, the Holepunch route makes a Dockerfile that isn't as easy to troubleshoot as using the current the R-Conda system route. Dockerfiles are essentially a last ditch configuration file that MyBinder can handle. The reason being the other configuration files are much easier and don't require knowing Dockerfile syntax. MyBinder aims to offer the ability to take advantage of Docker offering containers with a specified environment without users needing to know anything about Docker.

There is a Binder Help category for posting to get help at the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). Some other examples of posts already there may help you troubleshoot.

---

---

*Notice of a common pitfall*

Most of the [the configuration files](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/config_files.html) for making a repository Binder-ready are simply text and **can be edited right in the GitHub browser interface, without need to git or even cloning the repo locally.**

Last I knew, there **are two exceptions to this.** The `postBuild` and `start` configuration files have settings that allow them to be run as scripts and these get altered in a way they no longer work if you edit them via the GitHub browser interface. (This was my experience when last I tried. Your mileage may vary or things may have changed now.) To edit those, you have to have git available on a system you have and pull one from some other source. Then edit that on your machine that has git working & add it your repo and push it back up from your local computer.

(If this is a problem, you can post in the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) Binder help category and you and I could coordinate where I fork and edit those files in your repo to your specifications and then make a pull request to update your source of the fork with those changes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jupyter notebooks extensively then it may make sense to use [Binder](https://mybinder.org/)

But if you simply want to use R and Rstudio, then all you need is docker. A good resource is

https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker

Comment: You don't need anything but a GitHub account to use [RStudio in your browser via MyBinder](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda). Docker would offer you more flexibility as things get updated because MyBinder and conda lag behind slightly. However, MyBinder is easier than Docker. As far ask I know all the Rocker content is offered via MyBinder. Lack of persistence is the big drawback of using MyBinder. You need to get used to that.